# Node JS Ongoing Shell Output

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, bash

I'd like to have Node parse output from an ongoing bash command and do things with it in parallel to the execution of the executed command.

For example,

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const child = exec('bash server.sh',
  (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
    }
  });
```

where server.sh is

```sh
yell () {
  echo "bing";
  sleep 1s;
  yell;
}

yell;
```

The process unfortunately hangs as the execution is waiting for server.sh to finish but it never does. Is there a way to process the output of server.sh as it appears?

Comment: Seems to me you have to do something about `child` to make this execute in the first place.

Comment: Correct, looks like I can add an event listener like so:
```
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event listener can be bound like so:

```js
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```